# exec() PHP command fails without error but works on command prompt (Magento 2)

Tags: php, exec, magento2

I created an own command for magento 2 which exports all product data to a csv file, the command looks as follows:

```
php -d memory_limit=1024M /home/myuser/public_html/myapp/bin/magento catalog:export catalog_product -f csv -e myserializedarray >> /home/myuser/public_html/myapp/log.txt 2>&1 &
```

This command works perfectly on the command prompt, exports all 15000 products without a problem.
When I do the same within PHP as follows:

```
exec("php -d memory_limit=1024M /home/myuser/public_html/myapp/bin/magento catalog:export catalog_product -f csv -e myserializedarray >> /home/myuser/public_html/myapp/log.txt 2>&1 &")
```

The command stops after some minutes, always at different positions. I added some log statements and it turned out that it stops in the middle of the loop which reads data from the database and writes it into the a file. Magento function (core):

```
 public function export(){
    //Execution time may be very long
    set_time_limit(0);

    $writer = $this->getWriter();
    $page = 0;
    while (true) {
        ++$this->page;
        $entityCollection = $this->_getEntityCollection(true);
        $entityCollection->setOrder('has_options', 'asc');
        $entityCollection->setStoreId(Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID);
        $this->_prepareEntityCollection($entityCollection);
        $this->paginateCollection($this->page, $this->getItemsPerPage());
        if ($entityCollection->count() == 0) {
            break;
        }
        $exportData = $this->getExportData();
        if ($this->page == 1) {
            $writer->setHeaderCols($this->_getHeaderColumns());
        }
        foreach ($exportData as $dataRow) {
            $writer->writeRow($this->_customFieldsMapping($dataRow));
        }
        if ($entityCollection->getCurPage() >= $entityCollection->getLastPageNumber()) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $writer->getContents();
}
```

The user is the same for the command prompt version and for the version started via web. The used paths are absolute, therefore shouldn't be a problem either. I also activated error logging, but there's no messages written. `shell_exec` doesn't work either.

What am I missing? The function itself must be working, so what's the difference with starting the command via php?

Comment: The problem is that the calling php tries to wait for the exec call to finish, but eventually it gets shut down by its own time limit, and your export script gets aborted along with it. You should be able to prevent that by simply adding `nohup` before the command (i.e. `exec('php ...` -> `exec('nohup php ...` ). That way the request will only start the export and continue. But you will have to worry about showing the results, and multiple exports running at the same time, and so on. So it's probably not a good solution, but one you can test quickly.

Comment: Thanks @jh1711, but this unfortunately didn't make a difference. The process wasn't waiting for a result before too, it was asynchronous because of the `&` at the end.